# How to implement Copy in WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to implement a Copy operation for a datagrid configured with

```
SelectionMode="Extended"
SelectionUnit="Cell"
```

I have figured out (mostly) how to get content from the cells in the DataGrid.SelectedCells collection - Text columns, Combobox columns, and Templated columns.
Determining how many columns are involved seems pretty straightforward:

```
var cols = selectedCells.Select(c => c.Column.DisplayIndex).Distinct().ToList();
Debug.WriteLine($"Found {cols.Count} columns.");
```

However, I can't figure out if the cells are on different rows.
I think I need that information to use appropriate separators between cells to indicate multiple rows. 
DataGrid.SelectedCells is an

```
IList<DataGridCellInfo>
```

The DataGridCellInfo has an

```
object Item
```

property, which is an item in the collection the datagrid is bound to.  I don't think that helps...

Any ideas or pointers would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve the row index using `DataGrid.Items.IndexOf(cell.Item)`, where `cell` is `DataGridCellInfo`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.